# Python namedtuple: Type names and field names must be valid identifiers: '480w_still'

Tags: python, collections, valueerror, namedtuple

I'm trying to use `namedtuple` with a dict object to translate a dict to a custom class, but I'm having trouble. When using

```
self.images = namedtuple('Images', json["images"].keys())(*json["images"].values())
```

this exception is raised:

```
ValueError: Type names and field names must be valid identifiers: '480w_still'
```

I have seen people having these errors but haven't find a solution nor documentation on `480w_still`. Can anyone help me what that means and how could I solve it? Thank you.

The full json is:

https://pastebin.com/PmSyBSkb

The json with only the images part is:

https://pastebin.com/q3rWVmXa

Thank you.

Comment: the field names may not start with a number...

Comment: Is `'480w_still'` an element of `(*json["images"].values())`?

Comment: @SebastianLoehner I can not see field names in `json["images"]` starting with a number.

Comment: Oh, wait, yes it is, @Acccumulation , and I do see it, sebastian, sorry. How can I make it so it accepts numbers there? Or will I just need to deal with it?

Comment: Ah, I'll need to deal with it because It's a property name. My bad.

Comment: I get the same error when trying to use international letters - It's strange that is not possible to use international letters as identifiers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the namedtuple documentation:

> Any valid Python identifier may be used for a fieldname except for names starting with an underscore. Valid identifiers consist of
>   letters, digits, and underscores **but do not start with a digit or
>   underscore** and cannot be a keyword such as class, for, return, global,
>   pass, print, or raise.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Here's the link for Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple
The quoted paragraph can also be found there.